# Getting 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer while zipping to produce formatted list from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have following `ndarray`:

```
>>> tse = np.random.rand(10)
>>> tse
array([0.64021719, 0.23120137, 0.34434061, 0.98906763, 0.48684061,
       0.20250377, 0.34603949, 0.28329445, 0.99073352, 0.07970697])
```

I want to generate something like this from it:

```
e#0: 0.64021719
e#1: 0.23120137
e#2: 0.34434061
e#3: 0.98906763
e#4: 0.48684061
e#5: 0.20250377
e#6: 0.34603949
e#7: 0.28329445
e#8: 0.99073352
e#9: 0.07970697
```

I thought I will first generate list containing each of those lines and then concatenate that list elements with newline delimiter.

```
>>> ['e#' + str(i) + ': ' + str(e) for i,e in zip(np.indices(tse), tse)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1744, in indices
    res = empty((N,)+dimensions, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `print('\n'.join('e#%i: %.8f' % x for x in enumerate(tse)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt be using np.indices for that, look up what the function does here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html

Instead, try the following

```py
import numpy as np
tse = np.random.rand(10)
print(['e#' + str(i) + ': ' + str(e) for i,e in enumerate(tse)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tse = np.random.rand(10)
s = [f"e#{i}: {e}" for i, e in enumerate(tse)]
```